# WKWebView can not load CSS or JS or images from sandbox?

Tags: ios, sandbox, wkwebview

I using `loadHTMLString(_, baseURL:)`, baseUrl point to the `Documents`, it works on simulator, but it does not work on a real device.

why? Apple did not allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Use instead the method

```
let fileURL = <URL_to_html>
let documentsURL = <URL_to_documents>
webView.loadFileURL(_ URL: fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo readAccessURL: documentsURL)
```

It is the method that is provided exactly for that purpose.

`WKWebView` loads files needed for the web page in a different system process, and iOS does not allow it to access your app's sandbox by default. With this method, it should do so.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `loadFileURL`, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work.
I think it is because the images and html are not in the same directory.